# Fourier transform of linear function

Tags: fourier-transform

When computing the Fourier transform of a linear function I get the following result,

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \ x \ e^{i k x} & = \frac{1}{i k}x \ e^{ikx} \Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{i k} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \ e^{i k x}\\
& = \lim_{\Lambda \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{i k} 2\Lambda \cos(\Lambda k) -\frac{2 \pi }{i k}\delta(k).
\end{align}

While the second term is the usual expression appearing in the literature, I am confused about the first one. How do I deal with that term?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your integral expression diverges and you need some functional analysis machinery to proceed further.

Comment: @user3716267 is correct. A good way to do this is to multiply all your integrands by a (Schwartz) test function $\varphi$, and then you can do your integration by parts. You'll see the that first term is $0$. It's essentially using the theory of distributions to make sense of Dirac deltas.

Comment: Ah right that makes sense. Thanks!